# What's the difference between "governance" and "management"?

Tags: differences

I am a programmer and I always heard about there're some systems called themselves as Service **Management** System and some other called Service **Governance** System.

I understand both of the two words are trying to express the meaning of "control something", but I'm not sure what's the actual difference between the meaning of the words.

What's the difference between them?

Comment: Have you any experience of either type of system in operation and what type of service do they manage and govern? The difference _should_ be that a _management_ system is concerned with running the service at a more or less detailed level but a _governance_ system provides oversight of the service. For instance with regard to compliance with the law or with the terms of a Service Level Agreement. However it wouldn't be the first time that I'd seen marketing departments give software products misleading names.

Comment: My own work in the finance area of a large organisation (the Financial Governance and Performance Directorate) covers both of these. I would say that both have scope down to individual transactions, as well as the wider view. I would summmarise governance as concerning itself with whether actions are in accordance with the law, and internal finance policy, and performance as to do with issues such as efficiency, timeliness, value for money, etc. Some of these straddle the boundary, and that is where my job gets interesting. For example, inclusivity and sustainability.